# Unable to refresh JTable content after inserting data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am implementing JTable as user registration form, I am almost done, but when an data is added its not showing latest data entered and also the size of JTable is very small. How can i increase that?

code is in below link [JTable Implementation](http://pastebin.com/mbTQJCfF)

Comment: please show a SSCCE here instead of that monster dump on pastebin ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table won't magically know when you've added data unless you tell it.

Take a look at [DefaultTableModel#addRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

Once you've inserted your new row into the data base, you need to add it to the table model.

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DefaultTableModel myData = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(myData);
```

// initialize the table with model type constructor

```
   String offer = "pankaj ";
    Object [] rowData=new Object[]{offer,null};
```

//convert string into object array
       myData.addRow(rowData);

//use addRow(Object[] rowData) method of defaulttablemodel class